# Reading a file with scanner

Tags: java

EDIT: I ADDED A NEW PART to catch fileexception error

This is a pincheck program. I'm supposed to create a txt file with the following lines:

> peter, 1212
>   john, 1234
>   mary, 0000

I then have to write a java program to prompt user for the file path of the txt file then key in their name and pin number. I'm able to compile my code but I don’t get the expected result when I type in the correct name and pin.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PINCheck {
  public static void main(String[]args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter file path: ");
    String filepath = s.nextLine();

    File passwordFile = new File(filepath);

    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    String name = s.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
    String password = s.nextLine();

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(passwordFile);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            if (password.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*")) {
                System.out.println("You have entered a non-numerical PIN!");
            } else if (sc.hasNext(name) && sc.hasNext(password)) {
                System.out.println("You have logged in successfully.");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Login Failed.");
            }
            break;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are providing static string in file path which will look for filepath , remove double quotes from filepath.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "My code can't seem to run properly" is incredibly vague, as is "I can't seem to 'login' successfully" - what's going wrong? Please give more details. (I suspect you're not using `hasNext(String)` properly, aside from anything else...)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt responses. Im able to compile my code but its not running as intended.
When i type in name and pin number that can be found in the txt file its supposed to return as i have logged in successfully.
however i'm not sure if i have used scanner the right way in this.

Answer (score 0):

This line : `Scanner sc = new Scanner("passwordFile");` implies that Scanner will scan from the String specified in the constructor and not the actual file.

Use `Scanner sc = new Scanner(passwordFile);` instead.

A similar mistake for `File passwordFile = new File("filepath");`.

Use it like `File passwordFile = new File(filepath);`

In both cases, pass the variable, not the string.

Comment: after editting a new error comes up, unreported exception FileNotFoundException. Why does this happen? 

Sorry im very new to java, just picked it up only a month ago

Comment: Because the file was **not** found ? Is the file in the same directory where you are executing the java application ? Study how to access files in arbitrary location.

Comment: I'm suppose to prompt user for the file path. The error comes up when compiling the code.

Comment: Then wrap your file access code inside a `try-catch` block and catch the `FileNotFoundException`.